# Can you identify these 2 retro bricks? A red piece with notch and steps, and a green circle

Tags: part-identification, piece-information, vintage, fabuland

No idea about these parts. The green part is roughly 5x5, 6-01 code and old school Lego brand written on it. The red part has a notch and what kind of looks like internal steps. Thanks!

[image: red and green vintage pieces]

Answer (score 9):

1st is a train part, [Plate, Modified 1 x 2 with Steam Engine Cylinder, Round Surfaces, Interior Grooves](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=x461b&colorID=5)

2nd is [Fabuland Trash Can Lid 5 x 5](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=fabef6&colorID=6)

Comment: Great, thank you!

Comment: I thought red was a train part, but it's not under the Train category. And I never got to searching for "Cylinder". The trash can lid I should have posted about, since I have the can itself, and it says LEGO on it as well, but also has no part number, so that would've been an easy match.

Comment: @Curtis <https://bricks.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers>

Comment: @RSchulz, on bricklink, if part of an element is plate like it's usually under Plate, Modified, even if it's only used in train sets...

Comment: Yeah, but I wasn't about to go through all of **those**. It just seemed to... train-specific.